# Cannot log in to smb server from Linux, credentials are never asked

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing

We have a Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS, with a smb server for Mac and Win access.
Mac and Win access works fine.
However, if we try to connect to the smb server from another Ubuntu or RedHat desktop system using Network browsing, Windows network, we can see the server under the correct name in the correct workgroup, but a double-click on the symbol opens it without any login dialogue, and it shows no content.

What are we missing?
Is it something in the `smb.conf`?

```
root@nnn:~# smbd -V
Version 4.3.11-Ubuntu
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment as I don't have enough rep yet, but has your smb.conf got anything to allow Guest or Anonymous access to any SMB shares?

It sounds like your RHEL/Ubuntu client is automatically trying to login anonymously, which your server is letting it do.

You could try creating a new share and adding the line:

```
guest ok = yes
```

and see if your RHEL/Ubuntu client can see this share in the file manager (without having entered credentials). If this does appear, you know your client is authenticating as guest and can take the necessary steps to disallow (or restrict) that on your server. Alternatively, if you want to keep some shares available to guests (and therefore don't want to remove guest access) you could look into using /etc/fstab to mount your SMB shares using correct credentials.